# Need Intel graphics drivers but have to use nomodeset to boot

Tags: boot, drivers, graphics

My laptop uses Intel graphics card but I have to use nomodeset to boot, is there anything else that I can do to boot without nomodeset?

System Specs:

```
Memory: 4 Gb  
Processor: Intel® Celeron(R) CPU N3060 @ 1.60GHz × 2  
Graphics Driver: llvmpipe (LLVM 9.0.1, 128 bits)  
Graphics Card: Integrated Intel Graphics Card  
OS Version: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
```

I am new to Ubuntu and AskUbuntu.

Update 1:

It still freezes, But when I boot with nomodeset it says :

```
[    1.038310] Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed    
/dev/sda5: recovering journal    
/dev/sda5: clean, 269777/781568 files, 10749001/31232256 blocks   
[    14.830987] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f
```

then goes to the splash screen. It also says "System program problem detected". Do you think this could be part of the problem?

Update 2:

fsck doesn't give any errors, the bluetooth is internal, and i still get the initramfs error. I also have ' `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_backlight=vendor"` ' instead of ' `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` ' in "/etc/default/grub" to fix missing brightness sliders.

Comment: Why do you have to boot with nomodeset? Let me guess... it hangs at the Ubuntu logo when booting?

Comment: Yes. It just freezes.

Comment: When you update this question, you have to let me know by a comment that starts with @heynnema or I'll surely miss it, like I just did. Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the exact make/model of your computer.

Comment: I'm not finding what I'm looking for at the Dell web site. Give me the Service Tag ID from the bottom of the laptop.

Comment: @heynnema Bios Version: 4.4.0 and my laptop: Dell Inspiron 15-3552

Comment: @heynnema I solved it but it won't let me set my solution as solved until tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by disabling "Load Legacy Option Rom" in the bios. Now everything works and it is detecting my graphics card.

Comment: Good find! Glad it's working now,

Comment: Can someone explain what this means?

Answer (score 1):

You may have a problem with an older computer, with an older GPU. Try this...

`sudo -H gedit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf` # edit this file

change:

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

to:

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

Save the file and quit `gedit`. Remove nomodeset. Then reboot.

**Update #1:**

You have additional problems.

**fsck**

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier

  - `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda5`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**crash logs**

Whenever you see "System program problem detected", make sure to click either "Send Report" or "Don't Send Report", don't just close the window, or you'll see the same message over and over again.

To manually clear out the current backlog of crash reports...

`sudo rm -i /var/crash/*.crash`

**initramfs**

For the "Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed" message...

`sudo update-initramfs -c`

**bluetooth**

For the "Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f" error, is this an internal bluetooth adapter, or an external USB bluetooth adapter?

**Update #2:**

*I solved it by disabling "Load Legacy Option Rom" in the bios. Now everything works and it is detecting my graphics card.*