# Why can my Pentium G3220 Thinkcentre only boot when using nomodeset in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, lenovo, intel-graphics, nomodeset

I got a Thinkcentre M83 with an Intel Pentium G3220 for cheap to have a PC for uni at my parents' place. I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on it. Even during the installation, I've had to use the "safe graphics" mode. Ever since installing it ten days ago I have been trying to get it to work without using `nomodeset`, but to no avail. Currently, in my `/etc/default/grub` I have it set to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"` so that it automatically boots using `nomodeset`. I am using the onboard graphics.

I have tried a few different things, namely:

- I checked whether `xserver-xorg-video-intel` is installed. It is. No changes there.
- I have tried uncommenting `WaylandEnable=false` in `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` as suggested in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1237682/1168102).
- I have tried changing the GPU from auto-detection to iGPU in my BIOS settings. I have also tried changing my BIOS boot to *UEFI only*, *Legacy only* and *Legacy first*. I am not sure if that is the same thing as *disabling Load Legacy Option ROM* as suggested in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1237938/1168102) and [on the archlinux forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=255430), but I did not see an option like that in the BIOS and a quick Google search didn't bring up any results. I have also tried resetting my BIOS. None of these tweaks changed anything.

Below are the outputs of `inxi`, `inxi -G`, `xrandr`, `sudo lshw -c display` and `lspci -k`. While I don't really understand a lot about them, I have noticed that the graphics device appears to be detected as an *Intel Xeon E3-1200*, with driver *fbdev*. This seems strange to me. From what I read on other threads, I expected it to have driver *i915*.

```
david@def:~$ inxi
CPU: Dual Core Intel Pentium G3220 (-MCP-) speed/min/max: 798/800/3000 MHz Kernel: 5.8.0-43-generic x86_64 Up: 35m 
Mem: 2315.8/7851.6 MiB (29.5%) Storage: 238.47 GiB (8.7% used) Procs: 227 Shell: bash 5.0.17 inxi: 3.0.38 
david@def:~$ inxi -G
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics driver: N/A 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: fbdev unloaded: modesetting,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~77Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 11.0.0 128 bits) v: 4.5 Mesa 20.2.6 
david@def:~$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080     77.00* 
david@def:~$ sudo lshw -c display
[sudo] password for david: 
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f7800000-f7bfffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
david@def:~$ lspci -k
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Lenovo ThinkCentre M83
    Kernel driver in use: hsw_uncore
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Lenovo Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
    Kernel modules: i915
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Lenovo ThinkCentre M83
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo ThinkCentre M83
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo ThinkCentre M83
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family KT Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family KT Controller
    Kernel driver in use: serial
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-LM (rev 04)
    DeviceName:  Onboard LAN
    Subsystem: Lenovo ThinkCentre M83
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo ThinkCentre M83
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo ThinkCentre M83
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo ThinkCentre M83
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Q85 Express LPC Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo ThinkCentre M83
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo ThinkCentre M83
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo ThinkCentre M83
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
```

What seems weird to me is that in most threads I have read, people seem to just have a black screen when booting without `nomodeset`. For me it is different. It looks a bit like a picture within a picture (first image), but then when I move the mouse it starts shaking around (second image). I can only move the mouse. Keystrokes do not get registered. When I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, however, I get to the login screen and everything looks normal and I can put in my password. As soon as I hit enter though, it's back to looking weird like in the images below. Any help would be much appreciated, since `nomodeset` doesn't seem to let me use a second screen which is very unfortunate.

[image: pic_in_pic_desktop_01]
[image: pic_in_pic_desktop_02]

Comment: I would try a lower hardware hungry version like Kubuntu.  https://kubuntu.org/ link to Kubuntu

Comment: @David
Would that require a complete re-install? Or is it as simple as following [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PureKDE) to install KDE and remove ubuntu-desktop?

Comment: Its a whole other Ubuntu OS yes a full re install.

Comment: @David While certainly an option, I'd view it as kind of a last resort, since there is no guarantee that it will work, but it is quite a bit of work. It is also not a solution, but rather a workaround. And since the same computer ran Windows 10 prior to me acquiring it, I don't think it is categorically to weak to run Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

The `nomodeset` flag tells the Linux Kernel to *not* load any video drivers and use the BIOS display mode until a window manager takes over the task of running the video subsystem. For the last decade or so, the kernel has generally handled all of the hardware specific clock rates and registers on the video card during boot so that you can see higher resolution, flicker-free splash screens.

Unfortunately, some video cards are less cooperative than others.

Looking at the output of `lshw -c display`, your i915 is showing as being `UNCLAIMED`. This is suboptimal. I would suggest trying to work out why the system isn't able to run the device properly by using this command:

```
sudo modprobe i915
```

I've seen on some Lenovo and Dell machine an error come back regarding the `enable_dpcd_backlight` option. If you see this error, you can resolve it like this:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Edit your `tuxedo-i915.conf` file as `root`:

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/modprobe.d/tuxedo-i915.conf
   ```

   ***Note:** Feel free to use whatever text editor you prefer.*
2. Find the row that contains `enable_dpcd_backlight` and comment it out. The line should now look like this:

   ```
   # options i915 enable_dpcd_backlight
   ```
3. Restart your computer

After rebooting, you should no longer see `UNCLAIMED` when you type `lshw -c display` into Terminal. Some of your graphics issues may also be better as a result and at this point you *may* be able to remove the `nomodeset` flag from your Grub configuration file.

Comment: `sudo modprobe i915` comes back empty. `/etc/modprobe.d/tuxedo-i915.conf` doesn't seem to exist.
`david@def:~$ sudo modprobe i915` gives nothing and 
`david@def:~$ ls /etc/modprobe.d/` gives 
`alsa-base.conf                  blacklist-modem.conf
amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf  blacklist-oss.conf
blacklist-ath_pci.conf          blacklist-rare-network.conf
blacklist.conf                  hid_apple.conf
blacklist-firewire.conf         intel-microcode-blacklist.conf
blacklist-framebuffer.conf      iwlwifi.conf`
Edit: Format not very nice in comments. Tried to clarify.